# How to pass a message from a webpage to a Safari extension (background/injected)?

Tags: safari-extension, browser-extension

It looks like that there is no way to pass a message from the script already in a webpage to a injected script or background page in a Safari extension.

Quite weird if true.

Comment: Maybe try sending a message to the global page, which can then send the message back to all injected scripts, or scripts in specific windows/tabs.

Answer (score 0):

`window.postMessage` allows you to send a message to the extension scripts on the same page.